# araxis merge for mac and git diff

Tags: git, git-diff, araxis

I'm trying to use command line git on os x in conjunction with araxis merge.

I'd like git diff foo to open it araxis

I've copied the utilties in the installer to /usr/bin

```
$ cd /usr/bin/
$ ls | grep araxis
araxisgitdiff
araxisgitmerge
araxishgmerge
araxisopendiff
araxisp4diff
araxisp4winmrg
araxissvndiff
araxissvndiff3
araxissvnmerge
```

I've modified my .gitconfig to contain the following:

```
[user]
    name = Me
    email = Me@Me.com
[push]
    default = simple
[diff] 
tool = araxis
[merge] 
tool = araxis
```

Executing the following still results in a command line diff:

$ git diff template.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a .gitconfig file on os x.

```
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
    keepTemporaries = false
    trustExitCode = false
    keepBackup = false
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[diff]
  tool = araxis
[merge]
  tool = araxis
[mergetool "araxis"]
    path = /Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/Utilities/compare
[difftool "araxis"]
    path = /Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/Utilities/compare
```

You can then diff all changed files by executing

```
$ git difftool
```

Answer (score 2):

You should run `git difftool` to get it to run your custom tool.

From the [`git config` man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> **`diff.tool`**
>             Controls which diff tool is used by **`git-difftool(1)`**.

If you want to use `git diff`, you need to set `diff.external` instead of `diff.tool`.  Be warned that doing so may cause you some grief if you ever connect to your machine remotely.

> **`diff.external`**
>   If this config variable is set, diff generation is not performed using the internal diff machinery, but using the given command.

For your case, you want something like:

```
[diff]
  external = /usr/bin/araxisgitdiff
```

Answer (score 0):

For 2014 - it looks like Araxis no longer uses araxisgitdiff or araxisgitmerge - instead it uses compare via the following:

```
git config --global mergetool.araxis.path '/Applications/Araxis Merge.app/Contents/Utilities/compare'
```